# What is "several values" in C++ initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization

This is a question about **C++ Primer(5th edition)** Chapter 3.2, Page 84,85.

> When we have a ***single initializer***, we can use either the direct or
>   copy form of initialization. When we initialize a variable from more
>   than one value, such as in the initialization of s4, we must use
>   the direct form of initialization:

```
string s4(10, 'c'); //s4 is "cccccccccc"
string s5 = "hiya"; // copy initialization
string s6("hiya"); // direct initialization
string s7(10, 'c'); // direct initialization; s7 is cccccccccc
```

> When we want to use ***several values***, we can indirectly use the copy
>   form of initialization by explicitly creating a (temporary) object
>   to copy:

```
string s8 = string(10, 'c'); // copy initialization; s8 is cccccccccc
```

What is the meaning of "***several values***"? The text above doesn't explicitly reveal it. And I can't understand "***single initializer***", is it opposite to "initialize a variable from more than one value"?

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/several

Comment: Oh, I understand, the `single initializer` is just use the value to initialize the string object. Both of copy and direct initialization can be used in this case. But when initialize from more than one value, the values are parameters of initialize operator `()' function, just as in s4, first value is **10** to indicate the number of characters, second value is **'c'** which indicate the duplicated character is 'c'.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit lol, unfortunately in this case "several" really just means "more than one"

Comment: What's really being described here is that the "direct initialization" syntax will call a single parameter constructor for you, even though it doesn't look like a constructor.  It's also pointing out that there is no equivalent functionality for constructors with multiple parameters (it cannot be called in a way which doesn't look like a constructor).  This absolutely does not describe a better or worse way to do anything in the c++ language, it's just describing a syntax oddity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they mean when you want to pass multiple arguments to the constructor, you can't use copy-initialization without wrapping those arguments into a temporary:

```
string one1 = "one";
string one2("one");
string one3 = string("one");
```

vs:

```
string many1(10, 'c');
string many2 = string(10, 'c');
```

There are three forms for one argument, only two for multiple arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Several values refers to the number of constructor arguments.

Consider...

```
string s4(10, 'c'); //s4 is "cccccccccc"
```

There are two (i.e. several) values - 10 and 'c'.

In that situation you can't get the same behaviour from e.g....

```
string s4 = 10, 'c';  // doesn't work as above
```

...because the value to assign is evaluated as an expression with a comma operator: the left hand 10 is discarded, then the expression evaluates as simply 'c', which becomes the only argument to the string constructor.  There is no matching constructor taking a single char argument, nor anything the char can undergo Standard Conversion to, so you'll get a compilation error.  (The closest constructor is...

```
basic_string( size_type count,
          CharT ch,
          const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

...for whatever that's worth....)

With C++11 you can use braces to create a single std::initializer_list argument with which you can call the constructor...

```
basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> init,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

...but you could argue that's not calling a constructor with multiple values, but a single value containing sub-values....

Answer (score 1):

`10` is one value. `'c'` is another value. Together, they're two values used to construct a `string` object.

That's the point it's making: you can use `string s7(10, 'c');`, but `string s8 = (10, 'c');` won't do what you want, you can only use that form when you have a single initialiser.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, *several values* refers to the initialiser being called with multiple arguments.

As you already noticed, the text isn't really clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

In this context "several values" it means that the constructor has more than one argument.

This is the copy initialization that implicitly calls the constructor with one string argument:

```
string s5 = "hiya";
```

In this example, the constructor with two arguments has to be called explicitly:

```
string s8 = string(10, 'c');
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the meaning of "several values"?

I think the meaning is the number of arguments.

> When we initialize a variable from more than one value, such as in the initialization of s4, we must use the direct form of initialization:

Anyway, I think the copy form of initialization could be used with "several values" too, by [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11).

```
string s4 = {10, 'c'};
```

Answer (score 0):

The book terminology is confusing.

```
string s7(10, 'c');
```

This construct includes a single initializer, which is a list of values in parentheses. The book seems to imply each individual value is an initializer on its own right. This is incorrect.

Comment: I agree with you. I think the author should use ***single argument initializer*** here instead of just say **single initializer**. And then, the **"several values"** also should be replaced by **"several arguments"**.